# Catching publish errors in GCP PubSub and Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring-boot, google-cloud-pubsub

I have a Spring Boot application which needs to occasionally publish messages to GCP PubSub.  I implemented it following the instructions on the spring boot page (https://spring.io/guides/gs/messaging-gcp-pubsub/) so I have implemented the following configuration file:

```java
@Configuration
public class PubSubConfiguration {

    @Value("${myprog.pubsub.sms-topic}")
    private String topic;

    @Bean
    @ServiceActivator(inputChannel = "pubsubOutputChannel")
    public MessageHandler messageSender(PubSubTemplate pubsubTemplate) {
        return new PubSubMessageHandler(pubsubTemplate, this.topic);
    }

    @MessagingGateway(defaultRequestChannel = "pubsubOutputChannel")
    public interface PubsubOutboundGateway {
        void sendToPubsub(String text);
    }
}
```

From my rest controller, I autowire the message gateway and call `sendToPubsub`:

```java
@RequestMapping("/api/stuff")
@RestController
public class StuffController {

    PubSubConfiguration.PubsubOutboundGateway messagingGateway;

    @Autowired
    public StuffController(@SuppressWarnings("SpringJavaInjectionPointsAutowiringInspection") PubSubConfiguration.PubsubOutboundGateway messagingGateway) {
        this.messagingGateway = messagingGateway;
    }

    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST, path = "/go")
    public ResponseEntity<String> send() {
        messagingGateway.sendToPubsub("TEST");
        return new ResponseEntity<>("Ok!", HttpStatus.OK);
    }

}
```

This works, however due to our particular use case I would like to respond with an error if publishing fails.  If, for example, I configure a non-existent topic I would like to return a 500 error whereas it currently returns 200 and throws an exception asynchronously later. Is there any way I can access a future at the point of publishing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Spring Cloud GCP PubSub implementation uses Spring Integration framework and rely on it. For this, your send to PubSub method have to throw an exception as described in the [Spring integration documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/html/gateway.html#gateway-error-handling)

```
    @MessagingGateway(defaultRequestChannel = "pubsubOutputChannel")
    public interface PubsubOutboundGateway {
        void sendToPubsub(String text) throws MessagingException;
    }
```

Comment: Do you mean `org.springframework.messaging.MessagingException`?